# Group and sum items from one table based on column value from another table

Tags: php, mysql

Attached image:

[image: Structure Of Tables]

Okay, I keep running around in circles on this one and I know that when I see the solution, I'll facepalm in my own direction. Just pretty much brain dead at this point. Anyway.....

I need to sum the price of the "item" column on the orders table based upon the "type" column in the inventory table.

The inventory table is used as the criteria to create a lookup field for the "item" column in the orders table.

Each part number in the "item" column in the inventory table is given a "type" value (1 - 5). I need to get the total sum for each type in the orders table.

Hopefully that all makes sense. Thank you in advance for any assistance!

EDIT:

As requested, hopefully this will clear it up :)

In the inventory table, there are roughly 50 items. About 30 of these will be circuit board part numbers and are Type 1. Type 2 will be TV's. Type 3 will be logic controllers. Type 4 will be pumps. Type 5 will be meters.

So, I am trying to get the query to show:

```
ITEM TYPE  TOTAL PRICE

1      $xxxxxx
2      $xxxxxx
3   etc etc
```

Comment: Can you add some example? Existing data and expecting result. Please.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.item,i.type, SUM(price) AS sum_price
FROM orders o JOIN inventory i ON TRY_CONVERT(INT,o.item)=i.item
GROUP BY i.item, i.type;
```

Comment: This is tagged mysql

Comment: @Strawberry at the time I wrote the answer, there was a sql-server tag.